# Mixing pait with ratios

Tags: ratio

I was wondering if any of you could solve the following equation,

Green paint and yellow paint can be mixed in the ratio 4:7 to make a certain lime colored shade. If a painter has 500 ml of green and 650 ml of yellow, what volume of lime colored paint can be made?

I have tried to solve this by using up all the green paint, and then using what is left of the yellow paint, however, I get confused when I do this. I also tried to add 500 and 650 to make it easier, but this does not work either.

Thank a lot!

Comment: For the purpose of making lime green paint, it is the yellow paint that is in short supply. Use it all.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, I have done that, but what would I do next?

Comment: Either then calculate the amount of green paint used, and add, or more simply multiply $650$ by $\frac{11}{7}$.

Comment: Where did you get the number 11/7 from?

Comment: If there are $7$ yellow to every $4$ green, for every $7$ yellow we get $11$ of mixture.

Comment: Hi really sorry to bother you more, but how come you ended up with 11/7 (how did you end up with an improper fraction?) And how come you only use one of the paints, and not both of them I really appreciate your help thank you.

Comment: We use both paints of course, but if we used all of both the result would be too green. So we use $650$ of the yellow and $650$ times $\frac{4}{7}$ green paint, for a total yield of $650+650\cdot \frac{4}{7}$. which is $650\cdot \frac{11}{7}$.